# Node.js / Express js : Best practice to consume Webhook secret & type

Tags: node.js, express, if-statement, webhooks

I am working with an external API and need to consume its webhook notifications.

This external service will include in the notification a "secret", a static string for verification purpose AND "type of notification", the type can be (those are pure examples) :

- verification-approved
- verification-failed
- payment-approved
- delivery-confirmed
- etc ...

So I first have to verify if the secret matches mine then run some work (mostly database) based on the notification type.

I would like your recommendations on the optimal approach to consume these webhook notifications.

My only idea is having multiple **if**s in the code, an **if** to check the secret and **n if**s to check notification type and run the corresponding work.

Here is an example of a webhook notification :

```
{ enduser_id: 'xxxxxxxx',
  owner: 'xxxxxxxxx',
  type: 'verification-approved',
  created_at: '2020-11-09T19:00:35.944Z',
  notification_id: 'yyyyyyyyyy',
  secret:
   'the_secret' }
```

Comment: You can use switch instead of so many ifs.

Comment: If you are doing lot of work with the data provided by the Webhook, verify the secret & then pass the data to async function (or a queue) so that you can return response to the webhook provider fast. Otherwise, if your business logic with the data takes long time, the webhook provider will consider timeout and it will retry the same payload again.